# React Native Hot Reloading

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have created a React Application via Expo CLI, while I run something via:

```
yarn web
```

I am able to open a QR code, and Switch to Tunnel and open that application via my Personal Android Device, it renders fine. But I have to make any changes, and I spin the server again using the same command, it does not seem to refresh content. It does refresh on Web, but does not on Android.

I have gone through few SO's posts and seen that we need a Hot Reload to serve contents dynamically. But when I shake the phone rigorously, I do not find any thing such as Hot Reload to enable it.

This is what I am getting:

[image]

I need two things now so to unblock me:

1. How to enable Hot Reload?
2. How can I rebuild the package so that I can access the latest from Android mobile

Answer (score 0):

I used expo start instead of yarn web,
And it has helped me in auto reloading